# How to set the number of objects created for Sequence (Laravel 8)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, factory, seed

I'm trying to create 30 news using Seeder and Factory. But I need to create 10 news with a non-empty field value `published_at` (Carbon) а для остальных случайное значение (Carbon/NULL)

In the documentation I saw such an example, it creates 5 records with the value `admin (Y)` and 5 more records with the value `admin (N)`

```
User::factory()
    ->count(10)
    ->state(new Sequence(
        ['admin' => 'Y'],
        ['admin' => 'N'],
        ))
        ->create();
```

So far I'm using this code, but I can't figure out how to add the number of records being created with a certain parameter value `published_at`. For example, 10 with Carbon and 20 with NULL.

```
/** ArticleSeeder */
Article::factory()
    ->count(30)
    ->state(new Sequence([
        'published_at' => Factory::create()->dateTimeBetween(
            now()->startOfMonth(),
            now()->endOfMonth()
        ),
    ]))
    ->create();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within a sequence closure, you may access the $index property that contains the number of iterations through the sequence that have occurred thus far.

Below is the simplest logic that you can use to achieve what you want.

```
Article::factory()
->count(30)
->sequence(fn ($sequence) => [
    'published_at' => $sequence->index < 10
                      ?  Factory::create()->dateTimeBetween(
                             now()->startOfMonth(),
                             now()->endOfMonth()
                         );
                      : null
])
->create();
```